# RestKit didFailWithError always called, didLoadObjects never called

Tags: restkit

Well, the title pretty much says it all. I'm calling my server and when it suceeds or fails it calls my didFailWithError method, never calling my didLoadObjects method. I would have expected didFailWithError to be called when, say, I get a 401 back, and didLoadObjects to be called when I get a 200 back.

Here's how I set up my object mapping:

```
- (void)setupCreateAccountMapping
{
    // mapping for CreateAccount
    RKObjectMapping* createAccountSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CreateAccount class]];
    [createAccountSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"email", @"pwd", @"uname", nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:createAccountSerializationMapping forClass:[CreateAccount class]];

    // mapping for CheckUserName
    RKObjectMapping* checkUserNameSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CheckUserName class]];
    [checkUserNameSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"uname", nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:checkUserNameSerializationMapping forClass:[CheckUserName class]];    

    router = [RKObjectRouter new] ;
    [router routeClass:[CheckUserName class] toResourcePath:@"/registration/rest/users/isavailable" forMethod:RKRequestMethodGET];    
    [router routeClass:[CreateAccount class] toResourcePath:@"/registration/rest/users/create_account" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router = router; 
}
```

and here is how I post to the server.

```
- (IBAction)submitPressed:(id)sender {

    CreateAccount* user = [CreateAccount new];
    user.email = [emailAddressTextField text];
    user.uname = [usernameTextField text];
    user.pwd = [passwordTextField text];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user delegate:self];
}
```

In didFailWithError I check:

```
if ([response statusCode] >= 400) {
```

to see if I succeeded or not and that seems really, really, wrong.

What am I doing wrong here? When I run the sample code I do see didLoadObjects called.

Here is the log from 2 runs, the first unsuccessful and the second successful:

Here we can see me trying to create a user named "andrew" but one already exists. I get a 406 back and didFailWithError is called.

```
2011-12-14 10:52:33.376 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:389 Reachability to host '127.0.0.1' determined for client <RKClient: 0x900c9d0>, unsuspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x900eee0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5>
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2011-12-14 10:53:16.478 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:362 Sending asynchronous POST request to URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/registration/rest/users/create_account.
2011-12-14 10:53:16.478 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:302 POST or PUT request for source object <CreateAccount: 0x6d1d8e0>, serializing to MIME Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded for transport...
2011-12-14 10:53:16.479 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:509 Starting mapping operation...
2011-12-14 10:53:16.479 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:510 Performing mapping operation: RKObjectMappingOperation for '__NSCFDictionary' object. Mapping values from object <CreateAccount: 0x6d1d8e0> to object {
} with object mapping RKObjectMapping class => CreateAccount: keyPath mappings => (
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: pwd => pwd",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: uname => uname",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: email => email"
)
2011-12-14 10:53:16.479 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:263 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'pwd' to 'pwd'
2011-12-14 10:53:16.479 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectPropertyInspector.m:107 Cached property names and types for Class 'CreateAccount': {
    accessibilityHint = NSString;
    accessibilityLabel = NSString;
    accessibilityLanguage = NSString;
    accessibilityValue = NSString;
    email = NSString;
    pwd = NSString;
    uname = NSString;
}
2011-12-14 10:53:16.482 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:273 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'pwd' to 'pwd'. Value: 123456
2011-12-14 10:53:16.483 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:263 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'uname' to 'uname'
2011-12-14 10:53:16.483 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:273 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'uname' to 'uname'. Value: andrew
2011-12-14 10:53:16.483 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:263 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'email' to 'email'
2011-12-14 10:53:16.483 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:273 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'email' to 'email'. Value: foo@example.com
2011-12-14 10:53:16.483 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:516 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2011-12-14 10:53:16.484 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://127.0.0.1:8080/registration/rest/users/create_account>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}. HTTP Body: pwd=123456&uname=andrew&email=foo%40example.com.
2011-12-14 10:53:16.572 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 406
2011-12-14 10:53:16.573 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:197 Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 32;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 14 Dec 2011 15:53:14 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
}
2011-12-14 10:53:16.573 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:202 Read response body: UserName or Email must be unique
2011-12-14 10:53:16.573 Ferret[60007:f803] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:289 Encountered an error while attempting to map server side errors from payload: Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.
```

Here we can see me trying to create a user named "andrewA" and the user is created. I get a 22 back and didFailWithError is called, not didLoadObjects

```
2011-12-14 10:54:21.486 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:362 Sending asynchronous POST request to URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/registration/rest/users/create_account.
2011-12-14 10:54:21.486 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:302 POST or PUT request for source object <CreateAccount: 0x9041300>, serializing to MIME Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded for transport...
2011-12-14 10:54:21.486 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:509 Starting mapping operation...
2011-12-14 10:54:21.486 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:510 Performing mapping operation: RKObjectMappingOperation for '__NSCFDictionary' object. Mapping values from object <CreateAccount: 0x9041300> to object {
} with object mapping RKObjectMapping class => CreateAccount: keyPath mappings => (
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: pwd => pwd",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: uname => uname",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: email => email"
)
2011-12-14 10:54:21.486 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:263 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'pwd' to 'pwd'
2011-12-14 10:54:21.486 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:273 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'pwd' to 'pwd'. Value: 123456
2011-12-14 10:54:21.494 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:263 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'uname' to 'uname'
2011-12-14 10:54:21.494 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:273 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'uname' to 'uname'. Value: andrewA
2011-12-14 10:54:21.494 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:263 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'email' to 'email'
2011-12-14 10:54:21.494 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:273 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'email' to 'email'. Value: fooA@example.com
2011-12-14 10:54:21.494 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:516 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2011-12-14 10:54:21.495 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://127.0.0.1:8080/registration/rest/users/create_account>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}. HTTP Body: pwd=123456&uname=andrewA&email=fooA%40example.com.
2011-12-14 10:54:23.004 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 200
2011-12-14 10:54:23.004 Ferret[60007:f803] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:197 Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 45;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 14 Dec 2011 15:54:20 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0; JBossAS-6";
}
2011-12-14 10:54:23.004 Ferret[60007:f803] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:202 Read response body: 98a454470b8b1cf0d3e081f3e2ac2ca41323878059558
2011-12-14 10:54:23.016 Ferret[60007:1531b] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:214 No object mapping provider, using mapping provider from parent object manager to perform KVC mapping
```

Notice in both cases I'm getting a non-JSON response back from the server, but it is just a string, like the error message or the activation code.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting back HTTP 200? Can you double check that in RestKit logs?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting 200 back

2011-12-13 16:23:08.174 Ferret[45270:f803] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest Yup!
HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}. HTTP Body: pwd=12345&uname=aaaaa&email=foo%40example.com.
2011-12-13 16:23:09.881 Ferret[45270:f803] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 200

Comment: well maybe the server sends some data in response? If so, the restkit perhaps does not have any clue how to map it & fails.

Comment: Can you perhaps paste the full log somewhere?

Comment: @mja: that's certainly could be the case. It is sending me data back and I've not setup mapping for it. (I actually don't care too much about the data in the success case you see...)

Comment: @mja: which log do you want? Full trace from my run? Or a trace from the server?

Comment: I'd prefer the trace from RestKit/app.

Comment: @mja: I've added the logs from 2 runs. Thanks!

Comment: You have your Content-type: set to "application/json" and the response is not a well-formed JSON, so i believe restkit bails out due to the parsing problem. Can you modify the server output eg. to return a JSON or to set appropriate content type header?

Comment: I suspected as much. Can you post that as an answer and then I'll green check you? And yes, I should be able to get my server to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @mja: forgot to tag you in the last comment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `Content-type` header set to "`application/json`" and the response is not a well-formed JSON. I believe the mapping process bails out due to the parsing problem. You can try modifying the server output eg.return a JSON or to set appropriate content type header.